# Javascript sequence of keys redirect function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function where if a specific sequence of keys are pressed then there will result in a redirect function. I know how to do just 1 character but don't know how to redirect after a sequence of them. So far this is the code:

```
document.onkeydown= function(key){ reactKey(key); }

function reactKey(evt) {
   if (evt.keyCode == 73) {
      if (evt.keyCode == 76) {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
      }
   }
}

  });

}
$(document).ready(main);
```

New code:

document.onkeydown= function(key){ reactKey(key); }

```
function reactKey(evt) {
    if(evt.keyCode== 73) {
    string key1 = 73;
    }{
    if(evt.keyCode== 76) {
    string key2 = 76;
    }{
    if(key1 === 73 && key2 === 76) {
      window.location = "http://www.google.com";
      }
   }
}
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: You can't do both tests in one event handler. You need to test once, store some kind of flag, and then test again for the second key. For longer sequences, you might consider storing an array of the last X keys pressed, and then, on each key press, comparing the array with what you want to trigger the redirect.

Comment: How fast should be sequence? what is timeout between presses to consider them sequence?

Comment: Not really sure how to store a flag. I updated the code but it doesn't work. 

@BorisIvanov
the time doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Amadan wrote, you have to store last two key strokes in array and compare it with needed sequence. Also, @Boris Ivanov as hinted, it would be good to check interval between key strokes.

Here is implementation:

```
var INTERVAL = 500; // max. interval between two last key strokes
var aKeys = []; // two last key strokes
var laststroke = 0; // timestamp of last key stroke
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    var t = (new Date()).getTime(); // current timestamp
    aKeys.push(event.keyCode);
    aKeys = aKeys.slice(0,2); // truncate aKeys array to 2 elements
    // compare aKeys with needed sequence and check interval between key strokes
    if (aKeys.join(',') == '73,76' && t - laststroke < INTERVAL) {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }
    laststroke = t;
}
```

Comment: Use `Date.now()` instead.

Comment: If there are embedded spaces would it still work if I added this?:

    function removeSpaces(aKeys)

Comment: `aKeys` cannot contain whitespaces since its elements are `numbers`

Answer (score 0):

On each key event, add the current key code or key char to a string or array. Test the end of the string/array for desired input sequence. Either truncate the string/sequence to a certain limit or clear it on timeout so it doesn't get out of hand.